# Displaying messages on regular intervals on browser

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

This is what I have in my `Servlet`.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Initializing...");

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Inside Thread!!!");
            for(int i=1; i<5; i++){
                System.out.println("Date: " + new Date());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });     
    executorService.shutdown(); 
    // Some more piece of code is there 
}
```

**What I am doing here:**

I have created a separate thread where the date gets printed after `5 sec` in the console.

**What I want to do:**

When I run this code, I get this output printed in the console:

```
Initializing...
Inside Thread!!!
Date : Sat Nov 01 15:57:57 GMT 2014
Date : Sat Nov 01 15:58:02 GMT 2014
Date : Sat Nov 01 15:58:07 GMT 2014
Date : Sat Nov 01 15:58:12 GMT 2014
```

I want the same set of messages to be printed in a `jsp` page in such a way that the Date gets printed in an interval of `5 sec` (by sending multiple response to the browser whenever a `Syetem.out.println()` method is executed int he above code).

**Reason for pushing message from server:**

In the above example, I am printing simple messages in a loop. But in real scenario, there are some calculations, hence the messages will be available at different time frames (i.e. not after every 5 sec, some messages will be available in quick time while the other messages might take some more time). Hence if I push from the server, then I can push the messages whenever it is available.

**Unable to understand:**

I am not sure how to send multiple response to the browser from a separate thread (i.e. from `ExecutorService` in the above code). I was looking into the `setInterval` method present in `javascript` but am not sue how to frame this code using it.

I am free to use `jQuery` or `javascript` to get this work. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to push from the server, you should have the client make an AJAX request every five seconds, and you should return the snippet that you want printed from that endpoint.

Comment: In the above example, I am printing simple messages in a loop. But in real scenario, there are some calculations, hence the messages will be available at different time frames (i.e. not after every 5 sec, some messages will be available in quick time while the other messages might take some more time). Hence if I push from the server, then I can push the messages whenever it is available. Please suggest.